# How to enforce a string is "from" an object instead of an arbitrary one in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

The sample code is here

```
const CONSTANT = {
  KEY1: 'xxx',
  KEY2: 'yyy',
} as const;

function foo(key: How to design this type?) {
 // ...
}

foo(CONSTANT.KEY1); // ok!
foo('blahblahblah'); // should display error
foo('xxx'); // should display error; even the value are equal but I'd like to restrict to using "CONSTANT.KEY1"
```

Comment: So you want the value to be from an enumeration of values => create an `enum`. See @RobCo answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use an enum**
This is the cleanest solution and satisfies all your needs:

```
enum Constant {
  KEY1 = 'xxx',
  KEY2 = 'yyy'
}

function foo(key: Constant) {
  // key is 'xxx'|'yyy'
}

foo(Constant.KEY1) // ok
foo('blahblahblah') // not ok
foo('xxx') // not ok! (since xxx is not a key in the enum)
```

---

**Option 2**
Create a union of the types of the values. Because your object is marked as `const`, that union would be `'xxx'|'yyy'`:

```
const CONSTANT = {
  KEY1: 'xxx',
  KEY2: 'yyy',
} as const;

// Helper to get a union of the values of a constant
type ConstValues<Type> = Type[keyof Type]

function foo(key: ConstValues<typeof CONSTANT>) {
    // key is 'xxx'|'yyy'
}

foo(CONSTANT.KEY1); // ok!
foo('blahblahblah'); // not ok
foo('xxx'); // yes ok (since xxx is a value in CONSTANT)
```

---

**Option 3**
Pass the key instead of the value:

```
const CONSTANT = {
  KEY1: 'xxx',
  KEY2: 'yyy',
} as const;
  
function foo(key: keyof typeof CONSTANT) {
  const value = CONSTANT[key]
}

foo('KEY1') // ok!
foo('blahblahblah') // not ok
foo('xxx') // not ok!
```

Comment: Thanks! Enum is the man. However my question was simplified, I asked an incomplete question, my bad, so I wonder the possibility of computed string value. Like this `enum CONSTANT  { key1 = createName('XXX', 'Pre'), }` and createName is like `function(name, prefix) { return prefix ?  prefix + name : name; }`. I've read the documentation it says computed string is not supported. I'd like to know if there is any workaround or any magic method that I cannot think of? Thanks!

Comment: @MarsonMao In the enum you could list only the keys and then have a separate lookup object that holds the key to computed value pairs. Or put the names in the enum and only the prefix separate.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because javascript/typsescript uses **pass-by-value** and **NOT pass-by-reference**. So ts makes a **copy of the value** before passing it to the function, thats why it is a simple string as any other variable you declared.
In your case, the variable `key` in the function is not the same variable as `CONSTANT.KEY1`, they only share the type and value (because `CONSTANT.KEY1` got copied).
A possible solution would be to pass the whole `CONSTANT` object to the function (and maybe creating an interface beforehand to use it as a type).